# How can I resize a Paperclip image after it has been added to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've added 2000 pictures to my images table and I'm using the Paperclip plugin to create thumbs. I'm wondering if there's a way to go through the database and add another `:styles` element.

For example, when I added the images I had the following in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

However, now I want to add a `:large` attribute and have it applied to every image that's already in my table. Something like:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Is this possible? Or would I have to re-add all 2000 pictures?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If Paperclip is installed as a plugin, you can do this:

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Screenshot
```

where Screenshot is the name of the class with the attachment.

If it's installed as a gem, do this inside script/console:

```
Screenshot.all.each {|s| s.image.reprocess! }
```

replacing Screenshot with the appropriate class name

Comment: The second method is really helpful, I failed the first one with undefined method exception.

Comment: if you have a ton of screenshots you should use #find_each. Screenshot.find_each {|s| s.image.reprocess! }

Comment: The second method worked great on the `rails console` with Paperclip as a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
```

Comment: To me more specific: rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=MyClass